# Are 2 body weight measurement results of the same person 2 random variables or 2 samples of one variable?

Tags: probability, statistics

assume a guy measures his body weight daily, are the results ($W_{d_0}$) of today and tomorrow ($W_{d_1}$)  2 random variables or 2 samples of one variable?

Comment: There is a random variable $W$ that describes his weight. The first and second measurements, $W_1$ and $W_2$, are two different random variables, but they have the same distribution as $W$.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki Is it reasonable to consider $W_1$ as a sample of $W$?

Comment: Yes, a "sample" is a different random variable with the same distribution as $W$. Therefore, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are "samples".